# Azure function activity starts automatically after clicking on Run or Debug locally

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a HTTP Trigger Azure Durable Functions on C# and I use Azurite as local storage for the function. So when I run or debug the project locally, the activity functions are triggered automatically without any http request. I stop debugging, then start it again, the problem is gone. It does not do that the second time.
However, this has become annoying. Every time I have to start, stop and then start again if I want to debug.
Maybe there is some caching somewhere that triggers activity functions automatically I don't know.
Here is my structure:

1. Starter function

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "orchestrators/{functionName}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
  [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
  string functionName,
  ILogger log)
  {
```

2. Orchestrator

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(SynchronizeAllCoursesOrchestrator))]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SynchronizeAllCoursesOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
   var input = context.GetInput<FunctionInput>();
   return await context.CallActivityAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(nameof(SynchronizeAllCourses), input);
}
```

2. Activity function

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(SynchronizeAllCourses))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context, ILogger log)
{
```

So whenever I click start/debug, the activity function runs immediately. I then have to stop, and re-run all the time for it to listen to requests and not run immediately. How do I stop it from not running immediately?

Comment: There could be something stuck in the tables/queues used by Durable Functions and it keeps retrying that. Check your Storage Emulator; you can delete the tables/queues/blob containers and Durable Functions will re-create them on startup.

Comment: I already checked for that. But Azurite does not have any command to invalidate local  caches or empty the storage/queue/blobs.

Comment: You can use Azure Storage Explorer to check contents and remove things as well: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer

Comment: Installed Azure Storage Explorer and realized that Azurite has been creating a lot of unnecessary stuff and not deleting it after use. So somehow all those stuff was being picked up (remembered). Thank you @juunas for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @juunas 's answer above, I was able to solve the problem.
I have installed Azure Storage Explorer after running Azurite locally and realized that Azurite has been creating/saving a lot of data and not deleting it when stopped. So I manually went through and cleared all the tables, and it started to behave accordingly.

In short, it is enough to just clear `testhubname-workitems` queue before running. Then you won't get the problem again.

[image: Azure storage explorer navigation blade]

**Additional information edit:**

After further suggestions from @juunas . I set my hubName to "SerhatsDurableFunctionsHub" and I was able to rename the storage names to:
[image: CustomHubName]

Here is how my host.json file looks like:
[image: Host.json file]

Comment: So those "TestHub..." things are created for the Durable Functions "task hub" which stores the current state of orchestrations and also handles communication between orchestrators and activities. "TestHubName" is used as default if none is specified. I recommend that you set extensions -> durableTask -> hubName to something else in host.json in case you work on different Durable Functions projects on the same machine.